# How to choose the right permission access for /var/www/* folders?

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, webserver

I'm trying to configure my web server from scratch and since this is my first time doing everything on my own, I'm unsure what kind of permissions I need to set for each site I have in `/var/www`.

As of right now, I have the following layout for 2 of my websites that I host:

```
/var/www/ |-- blog.dev/
      |--  public_html/
              |-- .htaccess
              |-- wp-admin
              |-- wp-content
              ... 
|-- web.dev/
      |--  public_html/
              |-- .htaccess
              |-- index.php
```

As it is right now, my current workflow is mostly consisted of me **ssh**-ing into the server and occasionally uploading files via **sftp**. So, I need my user account to be able to modify everything alongside with apache being able to modify stuff as well when I, for instance, upload a picture via Wordpress blog.

So, I have assigned `chmod 775` to both public_html's and placed them in `chown www-data:www-data`, but am unsure if this is safe. `/var/www` is still owned by root, my user account is also placed in `www-data` group. My question is, what could I do to improve the overall setup. This feels extremely awkward and clumsy; It just doesn't feel right the way I did it. What are some more fool proof ways to properly configure the permissions so that I can shield myself from potential compromise.

Comment: I think the directory structure has some formatting problems: are `blog.dev`  and `web.dev` subdirectories of `/var/www`, on the same level as the first `plublic_html`? Or maybe the first `public_html` is a subfolder of `blog.dev`? Please edit your question.